# Using rdflib with anzograph

Tags: python, graph-databases, rdflib, anzograph

I am using the community edition of anzograph.  I have no problem using the sparql http protocol, however when I try to use the graph store protocol via rdflib I get a result I don't understand.  I am running the docker image from the anzo website and have mapped ports `-p 80:8080 443:8443 7070:7070`.

Here is the snippet from jupyter notbook

```
import rdflib
import rdflib.plugins.stores.sparqlstore as store

store = store.SPARQLStore("http://192.168.1.104:7070/rdf-graph-store")
graph = rdflib.ConjunctiveGraph(store=store)


graph.query("select (count(*) as ?c) {?s ?p ?o}")
```

This gives the message

```
ValueError: You did something wrong formulating either the URI or your SPARQL query
```

and an http error 406, higher up in the stack.

Is there anything obvious I should be changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!  In spite of what the documentation says, using `/sparql` (rather than `/rdf-graph-store`) together with the graph store port of `7070` works.  So the correct snippet is:

```
import rdflib
import rdflib.plugins.stores.sparqlstore as store

store = store.SPARQLStore("http://192.168.1.104:7070/sparql")
graph = rdflib.ConjunctiveGraph(store=store)


graph.query("select (count(*) as ?c) {?s ?p ?o}")
```